# How to report Likelihood Ratio Test results

Tags: r, glm

I am using a Likelihood Ratio Test (in R) to look for main effects in my model with three fixed factors (site, year, habitat) like this:

```
model1<-glm(tot.mass~hab, data=biom, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
anova(model1, test="Chisq")
model2<-glm(tot.mass~year, data=biom, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
anova(model2, test="Chisq")
model3<-glm(tot.mass~site, data=biom, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
anova(model3, test="Chisq")
```

I was told that by using "anova(model3, test="Chisq")" I will find whether (in this example) adding in the term "site" significantly improves the model. From what I understand, since my p value is >0.5, site doesn't have a significant effect on my model (e.g. isn't a main effect for this response variable). My output looks like this:

```
     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)
NULL                   687     1681.2         
site  2   16.543       685     1664.7   0.2884
```

My questions are 1) am I interpreting this correctly and 2) how would I report these results? Would I report the Deviance and pvalue ("Pr(>Chi)")?

Thank you!

Comment: Apparently you are trying to do model selection. Be sure to read and understand the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/11849).

Answer (score 1):

Some comments before answering this,

1) Always keep in mind that the order you test the terms in your model plays  significant role in their statistical significance. This happens because you sequentially compare models against each other (i.e. in your case you compared the NULL model (no predictors) against a model with "site" as the only predictor). If you add an extra variable then you comparing the model containing only "site" against a model containing "site" and "some other variable".

2) An easy way to remember that is by thinking of deviance as the "distance" between two models (chisq takes only positive values) so they further apart are two models the more likely is the variable added last to be statistical significant because the last model is more superior compared to the previous one.

3) When I am talking about  first, second, third,..., last model I am talking about the order you see these on the anova table in R.

4) This question is better to be placed in statistics section.

In your question now,

```
     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)
NULL                   687     1681.2         
site  2   16.543       685     1664.7   0.2884
```

1) Given the table above the model containing "site" doesn't provide any significant improvement (compared to NULL model) at the confidence level you mentioned, which might mean that variable "site" is statistical insignificant at the given confidence level, which is close to your interpretation.

However, If you want to be 100% correct what you get from that table is only this: "Given the table above the model containing "site" doesn't provide any significant improvement (compared to NULL model) at the confidence level you mentioned". And I think this is the correct answer to the question.

*Perhaps if you rearrange the variables and add some other variable first and then "site" you might find "site" statistical significant, though I think it unlikely.(Comment 1)

*Also using a different model (i.e. logistic) might give you a different result. So always remember that the thing you are testing is if a model is statistically better compared to another one. For example, a variable might be a good predictor of the response but because the functional form of your model is incorrect you might infer that the variable is statistically insignificant, which is wrong.

This is the way you would interpret this result.

2) You should report the Deviance  `16.543` , Degrees of Freedom `DF=2`and the p-value `0.2884`